# How to properly explode json and map to respective objects within arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, json, pyspark

I have a dataframe with an array column in the below structure :

| valueA | value B |
| --- | --- |
| First | [{"posts":[{"body":"post A"},{"body":"post B"},{"body":"post C"}],"subject":[{"id":"5571196","name":"author A","timestamp":"2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z"},{"id":"1076004","name":"author B","timestamp":"2021-12-25T07:34:27.524Z"},{"id":"1077532","name":"author C","timestamp":"2022-10-10T20:48:27.416Z"}],"communityName":"Cooking"}] |

JSON structure:

```
[{
    "posts": [{
        "body": "post A"
    }, {
        "body": "post B"
    }, {
        "body": "post C"
    }],
    "subject": [{
        "id": "5571196",
        "name": "author A",
        "timestamp": "2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z"
    }, {
        "id": "1076004",
        "name": "author B",
        "timestamp": "2021-12-25T07:34:27.524Z"
    }, {
        "id": "1077532",
        "name": "author C",
        "timestamp": "2022-10-10T20:48:27.416Z"
    }],
    "communityName": "Cooking"
}]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| value A | postsBody | author | authorId | timestamp | communityName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | post A | author A | 5571196 | 2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z | Cooking |
| First | post B | author B | 1076004 | 2021-12-25T07:34:27.524Z | Cooking |
| First | post C | author C | 1077532 | 2022-10-10T20:48:27.416Z | Cooking |

my original approach was to explode the posts array separately then the subject array and join them, but i keep getting

| value A | postsBody | author | authorId | timestamp | communityName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | post A | author A | 5571196 | 2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z | Cooking |
| First | post B | author A | 5571196 | 2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z | Cooking |
| First | post C | author A | 5571196 | 2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z | Cooking |
| First | post A | author B | 1076004 | 2021-12-25T07:34:27.524Z | Cooking |
| First | post B | author B | 1076004 | 2021-12-25T07:34:27.524Z | Cooking |
| First | post C | author B | 1076004 | 2021-12-25T07:34:27.524Z | Cooking |
| First | post A | author C | 1077532 | 2022-10-10T20:48:27.416Z | Cooking |
| First | post B | author C | 1077532 | 2022-10-10T20:48:27.416Z | Cooking |
| First | post C | author C | 1077532 | 2022-10-10T20:48:27.416Z | Cooking |

how can i properly map the respective posts and authors and get to the desired output?

Comment: If you control DataFrame *construction* it might be easier to process the data in a previous step to get it in the format you need **then** make the DataFrame.

Comment: @partTimeDeveloper, Would it be a problem to solve the problem with pandas?  I didn't see the pandas tag.

Comment: @Clegane - could try pandas.. this is running over a databricks environment, and pandas could potentially cause memory issues when this is run in a production setting.. that being said, open to trying a pandas solution if you have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the json format is always consistent as in your example:

- use the json module to read the string in `valueB` --> `stuff`
- `stuff` is a list with one item so `stuff = stuff[0]`
- the *body and posts* are associated positionally in the data so zip them then iterate
  `for (body,post) in zip(stuff['posts'],stuff['subject']):`

  - that produces dictionary pairs
    `{'body': 'mediterranean chicken kebab recipe'} {'id': '5571196', 'name': 'kayla obrien', 'timestamp': '2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z'}`
- extract the info you want with the dictionary keys and construct a list-of-lists or something that can be fed to a DataFrame
- or maybe just combine those dicts to feed to the DataFrame `body.update(post)`
  `{'body': 'mediterranean chicken kebab recipe', 'id': '5571196', 'name': 'kayla obrien', 'timestamp': '2021-10-20T08:41:09.124Z'}`